# Trying to understand C++ brace-initialization syntax better

Tags: c++, initializer-list, list-initialization

Why is the following code illegal?

```
for (int index=0; index<3; index++)
{
    cout << {123, 456, 789}[index];
}
```

While this works fine:

```
for (int value : {123, 456, 789})
{
    cout << value;
}
```

Code in IDEOne: http://ideone.com/tElw1w

Comment: [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) has members `begin` and `end`, but no `operator[]`

Comment: As T.C. already mentioned, `{123, 456, 789}` is not a type and also no expression - to go a bit further `decltype({1, 2, 3})` is defined being ill-formed. An exception is the type deduction when using `auto`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `std::initializer_list` does not provide an `operator[]`, it does have overloads for `begin()` and `end()` which are what the range based for uses. You can in fact index into an `initializer_list` like [this](http://ideone.com/23xl8e):

```
    for (int index=0; index<3; index++)
    {
        cout << begin({123, 456, 789})[index];
    }
```

Comment: Cool trick! And makes more sense than "some cases are special snowflakes."

Comment: Note the cost: one temporary array creation/destruction per iteration. For non-trivial types, this gets expensive quite fast.

Comment: It has to copy the ints from the `.data` section to the stack? Why? (Or worse, is it constructing a `vector<int>` or something?)

Comment: @T.C. good point, I wasn't advocating doing this, just illustrating it is possible though.

Comment: @StilesCrisis the standards says "An object of type std::initializer_list<E> is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated a temporary array of N elements of type const E, where N is the number of elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the std::initializer_list<E> object is constructed to refer to that array."

Comment: Note the "as if" part. It's up to the compiler.

Comment: It'd be cool to see if a reasonable optimizer knows how to optimize all the copies away.

Comment: @StilesCrisis For `int`s, you probably won't see copying. For more complex types, it may not be able to optimize it away (ctor/dtor might have side effects). Also, the pointer returned by `begin({...})` is only valid until the end of the full expression, so it's easy to use a dangling pointer by mistake.

Comment: Well, if you use a reference, couldn't you extend the lifetime of the object?

Answer (score 2):

A *braced-init-list* like `{123, 456, 789}` has no type by itself, and cannot be indexed (nor indeed used with most other operators).

The range-based `for` loop has special handling for this case to make it work. (Technically, the special handling is in the `auto&&` it uses internally, which deduces a `std::initializer_list` from a *braced-init-list*.)

Comment: So is there a list of contexts where a braced-init-list is legal?

Comment: @StilesCrisis There's a long note that summarizes it in [dcl.init.list]/p1. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28461182/2756719) has a quote.